# lucene multiple indexes from mysql tables

Tags: mysql, lucene

I have 3 tables (urls, textnodes, and titles) with 3 columns each in mysql. My question was, could I create multiple indexes in lucene and would this be necessary? The reason I want to do this is that if a hit appears inside a textnode...I only show the textnode (not the title or url), if its in the title, I only show the title and textnode (not the url).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understand the question.
Is there a relation between these three tables (say one webpage has a title, a url and a textnode)?
If there is then you could easily create one index where each document (webpage) has three fields. Then you can provide a query to match on the three fields (or on the one/s you need) and show the fields that you want.

Don't know if this answers your question, please clarify.

Comment: Try asking for clarification with comments instead of answers. Your suggestion seems to be on the right track if I read this correctly though.